# node koa REST (typescript) hangs on firebase database call

Tags: node.js, typescript, rest, firebase-realtime-database, koa

I have a simple `koa` **REST** service wrote in **typescript** that has a `GET` request the simply returns all users from a **firebase database** at db ref `/user`.

The request gets received by the app and it gets the database reference, but it **hangs forever** when it should get the value.

This is my `index.ts` file:

```
import * as Koa from "koa";
import * as Router from "koa-router";
import * as json from "koa-json";
import * as bodyParser from "koa-bodyparser";
import firebase from "firebase";
import { config } from "./config";

const app = new Koa();
const router = new Router();

router.get("/users", async (ctx, next) => {
  firebase.initializeApp(config.firebaseConfig);
  const db = firebase.database();

  const ref = db.ref("user");
  console.log("got ref");

  const snapshot = await ref.once("value");
  console.log("got snapshot");

  ctx.body = { users: snapshot.val() };

  await next();
});

app.use(json());
app.use(bodyParser());

app.use(router.routes()).use(router.allowedMethods());
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Koa started on port 3000");
});
```

And this is the output:

```
Koa started on port 3000
  <-- GET /users
got ref
[2021-02-21T10:09:03.818Z]  @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Namespace [masked-my-project]-dev-default-rtdb lives in a different region. Please change your database URL to https://[masked-my-project]-dev-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app (https://[masked-my-project]-dev-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/)
```

This is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "version": "2.0.2",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "lib": ["ES5", "ES6"],
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*"],
  "files": ["node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "koa-new",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "./node_modules/.bin/tsc-watch --onSuccess \"node .\"",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "firebase": "^8.2.9",
    "koa": "^2.13.1",
    "koa-bodyparser": "^4.3.0",
    "koa-json": "^2.0.2",
    "koa-logger": "^3.2.1",
    "koa-route": "^3.2.0",
    "koa-router": "^10.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
    "typescript": "^4.1.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "@types/firebase": "^3.2.1",
    "@types/koa": "^2.13.0",
    "@types/koa-bodyparser": "^4.3.0",
    "@types/koa-json": "^2.0.18",
    "@types/koa-logger": "^3.1.1",
    "@types/koa-router": "^7.4.1",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.31",
    "tsc-watch": "^4.2.9"
  }
}
```

`.env`:

```
FIREBASE_API_KEY=[mask]
FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN=[mask].firebaseapp.com
FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL=https://[mask]-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app
FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID=[mask]
FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET=[mask].appspot.com
FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID=[mask]
FIREBASE_APP_ID=1:[mask]:web:[mask]
FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID=[mask]
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66301224/koa-typescript-app-hangs-on-any-firebase-db-call) question, so I'm going to post the same answer as I provided there.

I have no experience using Koa with Firebase Realtime Databases (I have used Koa with Firestore to build REST APIs) so take this with a pinch of salt. To me it looks like you are doing everything right as far as fetching the relevant data from your Realtime Database. However, I've always stringified any objects that I would like to add to the response body, i.e.:

```
const responseBody = {
    'users' : snapshot.val()
}

ctx.body = JSON.stringify(responseBody);
```

Also, in the object that you are returning I believe that `users` should be within quotation marks (to act as a `string` type key in the object).

Finally, I also noticed that you are using `koa-bodyparser`. Firebase already parses the body, and `koa-bodyparser` cannot handle an already parsed body, which will be an object as opposed to an unparsed string. This can cause your calls to hang. Rather don't use `koa-bodyparser`, and when you need to access the request body use `ctx.req.body`.